# Using an NTuple parametric type vs using an abstract vector in Julia

Tags: julia

I am currently working on a parser which supports binary operations. The idea for representing a binary operation is to use a structure of this sort

```
struct Binary{T <: BinaryKind} <: Operation
    xs::Vector{Union{Operation, Atom}}
end
```

Where both `Operation` and `Atom` are abstract types. After reading the performance tips in the julia documentation, I have come to realize that a more efficient way of representing this structure would be

```
struct Binary{T <: BinaryKind, D <: Tuple} <: Operation
    xs::D
end
```

But Since I can have nested binary operations, I believe that there could be cases in which I would end up with very long type definitions, which could be even worse than just using an abstract type. Is there a way I can improve this?

Comment: Consider whether you really need to restrict the parameter `D`. You could just use `struct Binary{T <: BinaryKind, D} <: Operation`, unless the restriction serves a particular purpose.

Comment: The restriction does not serve a particular purpose, but since it would always be a tuple, I would end up with long nested types. Would avoiding to specify  the tuple content be better for type inference?

Comment: Well, can't you just not specify it, then, and drop typing the nested tuple altogether? I don't think it would make any difference for type inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (too long for the comment so I give it as an answer) that in this case it is probably better to be type unstable. Note that this is exactly what Julia does itself:

```
julia> x = :(1+2*(3+4))
:(1 + 2 * (3 + 4))

julia> dump(x)
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol +
    2: Int64 1
    3: Expr
      head: Symbol call
      args: Array{Any}((3,))
        1: Symbol *
        2: Int64 2
        3: Expr
          head: Symbol call
          args: Array{Any}((3,))
            1: Symbol +
            2: Int64 3
            3: Int64 4
```

Of course Julia has a significantly more rich syntax but even in your simple case consider the following. You get the benefits of type stability if you compile some part of code once and then run it many times (in this or other form).

Now I assume that what you write would be evaluated in practice mostly only one time. If you made your expressions fully type stable you have to pay each time (assuming that the expression changes):

1. the cost of compiling it (expensive)
2. the cost of running it (relatively cheap)

If your code would be type unstable you have to pay cost of compilation only once. It is true that running it will be a bit slower, but overall probably it will be better to do this this way.

On the other hand - if you expect that you define the expression only once and then run it many times, then probably a better approach is to use metaprogramming:

1. process your expression only once **and** generate Julia code that will be evaluating your expression
2. then Julia will compile the generated code once
3. you get a maximum performance of executing it after the steps 1 and 2 are made

---

A half-measure to your question would be to use the following data structure:

```
struct Binary{T <: BinaryKind, S} <: Operation
    xs::Vector{S}
end
```

In this way your code will be type-stable if `S` is a concrete type or a small union of concrete types, and type unstable otherwise (and I expect that then you can try to make the rest of the code to generate `xs` in a way that its `eltype` is concrete or a small union of concrete types).

(if you have more questions on this please comment and I can expand the answer)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some operations I need to change the expression, therefore the best solution would be probably to use the half-measure you suggested. This said, there are cases in which I am not alterating the expression and for which maybe using an approach based on metaprogramming would be better. I will probably consider a way to keep a data structure similar to the one I have now, but using Julia's expression syntax for when type stability is preferrable.